# "Note to self" - как лучше всего перевести?

Tags: перевод

"Примечание для себя" - явно не подходит.
"Напоминалка"?
Или же "Памятка"?
Встретил вот здесь: "*Note to self: Reduce length of the sessions to twenty minutes next time.*"

Comment: Может «заметка»? Но ведь «note» может быть и глаголом, «note to self» тогда можно перевести «заметь», «отметь», «обрати внимание».

Comment: Может быть, _на будущее_?

Comment: @jwalker: why not make it an answer?

Comment: @Quassnoi To me it's a simple translation request that is not worth a full answer. Besides, MigMit included it in his options.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Мне кажется, адекватного перевода просто не существует. В данном случае я перевёл бы так: `На будущее: уменьшить длину сессий до двадцати минут`, запихав `next time` туда же, в `на будущее`. В других контекстах возможен перевод `Не забыть:...`, или, с переходом в третье лицо, `он сделал себе мысленную отметку...` — в общем, много вариантов для частных случаев и ни одного универсального.

Comment: One thing to note about this expression is that we use it usually when something unfortunate happens and we don't want it to happen again. It's not usually a random reminder like, Note to self: call your mother tomorrow. We have to assume, in your example, that she regretted the session being that long for some reason and thinks to herself "I'll never do THAT again!"

Answer (score 3):

"Взять на заметку" is, in my view, a quite close translation.

Answer (score 1):

A simple yet accurate translation is:

> на заметку себе

Answer (score 0):

В учебнике русского для иностранцев было бы "обрати внимание!" с какой-нибудь картинкой. В "Лестнице", кажется, так и было :) А так, скорее, "заметка". Или NB (да, не по-русски, но используется часто, по крайней мере на филфаке :) ).

Answer (score -5):

Думаю, самая близкая по значению русская идиома, это "не наступай на грабли".